# Change elements in Python list with condition

Tags: python

I have this list

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I would like to convert elements greater than 3 as 0 so the list would become `[1,2,3,0,0,0]`

Here is my code

```
for i in range(len(x)): 
  if x[i] > 3:
    x = 0
```

I got this error message `" 'int' object is not subscriptable"`. could somebody tell me what I did wrong

Comment: `could somebody tell me what I did wrong`: Look at your code and think about what `x = 0` does.

Comment: After the first instance that `x > 3` you set the `list` `x = 0` from that point forward it is a _number_. You probably meant `x[i] = 0`

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your current code is, you are assigning `0` directly to `x`, not to the  item at a particular index, the same way you are comparing the value.

```py
for i in range(len(x)): 
  if x[i] > 3:
    # x = 0
    x[i] = 0  #<---- assign value at the index i
```

Or, you can just use a list-comprehension, and take 0 if the value is greater than 3, else take the value

```py
>>> [0 if i>3 else i for i in x]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```